# Is it possible to get the TeamViewer random password in an other way than by TeamViewer window interface?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, sudo, password, teamviewer

On my lubuntu 22.04 distribution is installed **TeamViewer (Classic)** version 15.41.7.

I know that for enable a remote assistance session by TeamViewer I have to send the Code ID and the session password to the assistant.
These information can easily acquired by the window opened by TeamViewer when it starts. This window is shown in the following picture where the password (**qm6yrux3**) is highlighted by a dashed rectangle:

[image]

My problem is that I can't show the previous TeamViewer Window on the monitor of my device so I need to know the **Client ID** and the **Random password** by an other way than by TeamViewer window interface.

#### Set the personal password

By this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/547206/how-to-find-my-teamviewer-id-on-ssh/838778#838778) I have learnt how to set the personal password (**not the random password** obviously) by command line ([teamviewer documentation](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/34447-command-line-parameters) not shows the command line option `passwd`):

```
> sudo teamviewer --passwd newPassword
```

To set the personal password must be use the `sudo` command.

#### Get ClientID by the file `global.conf`

Furthermore I can get the Client ID by the execution of the following command line:

```
sudo cat /etc/teamviewer/global.conf | grep ClientID
[int32] ClientID = 444672086
```

Previous command find the **Client ID** inside the file `global.conf` which is a configuration file of TeamViewer. Also to execute the previous command it is necessary the use of `sudo`.

#### My question

Because I'm not able to get the random password from that file, my question is:
it does exist a command to get the TeamViewer **random password** in an other way than by TeamViewer window interface?

Comment: Maybe use Teamviewer Host and Easy Access with trusted account? With that you can connect without password. But you would need license...

Comment: @SheldonCopper Thank you for the hint, I have found [this link](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/108681-best-practices-for-secure-unattended-access) and [this link](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/unattended-access-security/) about the topic. May be I'll evaluate your suggested way to use **Easy Access**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passwords are stored on your system encrypted as of version 10 if I remember correctly, so no: this is not possible. The only available info comes from:

```
sudo teamviewer info
```

and this does not hold the random password.

The only way to get the random password is to have the teamviewer interface active.

Comment: By the the command `sudo cat /etc/teamviewer/global.conf` I can get some configuration info, so not only with `teamviewer info`. Furthermore the command `teamviewer info` must be execute by `sudo` (as the previous command `cat`) otherwise it doesn't show the ClientID.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Teamviewer Host and Easy Access with trusted account. With that you can connect without password. But you would need license.

For example following links speak about **Easy Access** and could be useful:

- https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/108681-best-practices-for-secure-unattended-access
- https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/unattended-access-security/